# Transforming c2kschools.net into an App with Visual Studio

Tags: java, asp.net, web-applications, visual-studio-2013

I wish to develop a mobile App that simply makes use of the C2K service for schools website. It has an initial ASPX login page and once logged in, it goes to a personal index.aspx homepage.

What would be the best way to go about this using Visual Studio? I have looked at Apache Cordova but I am not sure about it. Advice on which package to use and what approach I should take to transform this website into an App would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Ching

Answer (score 0):

I think Cordova in Visual Studio should meet your requirement, you can simply create a blank project index.html and redirect this html to the, e.g. http://www.example.com/login.aspx

After compile, you can run your existing web inside the app.

However, the "LOOKING" of the web site will be changed, since the screen of the phone may be too small to display the content of the entire original web site, you may need to change the appearance of your original web site, otherwise the users may need to zoom-in zoom-out all the time when they browse the web site inside the phone app.